# How to use OpenConnect without blocking port 443?

Tags: vpn, ssl, cisco, tls, openconnect

I've migrated a Windows 10 machine to Ubuntu.

On Windows 10 I connected to a Cisco VPN through the **Cisco AnyConnect client**. It worked fine and **allowed me to use port `443` while connected to the VPN** (browsing in HTTPS, reading the emails, etc...) .

If I'm not mistaken, this *should* be related to the **Cisco AnyConnect client** trying DTLS over UDP by default (with a fallback on TCP in case it doesn't work).

I've connected to the same Cisco VPN from Ubuntu with the **OpenConnect Client**, which should behave the same.

It works fine but, when the VPN is on, the port `443` is blocked (it I try browsing or reading emails, it hangs).

I've tried changing the DTLS port from `443` to `10443`:

```
$ sudo openconnect -u myuser@acme.com --dtls-local-port=10443 vpn.acme.com
```

but I'm not sure how to read the output:

> ```
> POST https://vpn.acme.com/
> Connected to 11.22.33.44:443
> SSL negotiation with vpn.acme.com
> Connected to HTTPS on vpn.acme.com
> XML POST enabled
> Please enter your username and password.
> POST https://vpn.acme.com/
> Enter your one-time password (OTP). If you do not have an OTP, you must register an authentication device in your OneLogin user profile.
> Response:
> POST https://vpn.acme.com/
> Got CONNECT response: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
> CSTP connected. DPD 30, Keepalive 20
> Connected as 10.10.25.54, using SSL, with DTLS in progress
> Established DTLS connection (using GnuTLS). Ciphersuite (DTLS1.2)-(ECDHE-(null))-(AES-256-GCM).
> Unknown DTLS packet type f9, len 16
> ```

It seems it's running on `10443`, so the `443` from the previous output should refer to the handshake only (and not to the UDP connection):

```
$ sudo netstat -peanut | grep 10443
```

> ```
> udp        0      0 192.168.2.48:10443      11.22.33.44:443       ESTABLISHED
> ```

It **still blocks every traffic on 443**, though.

**How can I prevent the OpenConnect VPN client from isolating my entire computer?**

Comment: Are you using firewall?

Comment: @JoKeR Yes, I'm using UFW. 443 and 10443 are open, though. What are you thinking?

Comment: That's what I thought :) I'm using it too but my VPN provider told me to turn it off because they have implemented it in ther service and they may conflict with each other. Try to disable it and reboot the system.